# How can I dynamically fire an event for a textbox which is dynamically created?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I dynamically fire an event for a textbox which is dynamically created?
I have used this code:

`lab.Click += new EventHandler(lab1_Click);`

But this code is not working...

Comment: what error you are getting here..+

Comment: Asp.Net is not having click event of textbox. you can only use text changed event or use javascript or jquery for it.

Comment: Click event not exist for textbox in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically created controls have to be re added to page control hirearchy in the **Page_Init** event with the **same ID** with which you added it last them.

Then only the ASP.NET framework will match the post back data (which in your case will have data for TextChange) and hook control and the event to its event handler. Else nothings gona happen

Check this article for details

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515

Answer (score 0):

.net did not allow the Click Event over Text box. If you want that event fires when textbox loses the focus, you can use "lab_validate()" event.

There are many other events for TextBox choose what you feel suitable.

Comment: I have used :  t.TextChanged += new EventHandler(text_change);

Answer (score 0):

lab.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));